# Trigger Hadoop Command by JAVA code

Tags: java, jar, hadoop, command

How to trigger a jar working on Hadoop from a simple jar, so that it uses HDFS, Actully, I am manually running this command **bin/hadoop jar ~/wordcount_classes/word.jar org.myorg.WordCount ~/hadoop-0.20.203.0/input1 ~/hadoop-0.20.203/output2** in which I have provided Input and Output directory in HDFS and I am using word.jar here, I want to make it such that it automatically gets triggered from Java Project.

Comment: Can you explain better what is that you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to run a Mapreducer job such that it gets triggered by java class on an action and began after dumping of input set into input directory of HDFS

Answer (score 1):

In best of my understanding all you asking for is done by the Main of your jar. It read parameters, creates job configuration, sets input and output formats  and finally runs the job.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on the same problem. I have a program (let's call it Driver) that must implement the following method:

```
public void runJar(File jar, String mainClass, File inputDir, File outputDir);
```

To do this, I was calling `org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(String[])` which is what your command-line is calling. This works great **only if you're running Driver from the command line**.

If Driver is running inside a container (like Tomcat or Jetty), you're going to have a problem. You'll get errors like

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
```

This is because of how `RunJar` messes with classloaders. You need to manually create a classloader like so:

```
final ClassLoader original = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
try {
  URL[] urls = new URL[] { jar.toURI().toURL() };
  ClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(urls, originalLoader);
  Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(loader);

  Class<?> mainClass = Class.forName(driverClass, true, loader);
  Class[] argTypes = new Class[]{ Array.newInstance(String.class, 0).getClass()};
  Method main = mainClass.getMethod("main", argTypes);
  main.invoke(null, new Object[] { args });
} finally {
  Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(original);
}
```